# Python convert to integer or string

Tags: python-2.7

I have a string like below,

string str ="3rd Floor, aaa Mall, bbb, cccc, dd, ee, 123456 ,ff"

I have to extract "123456" from above string.

I am using below code to extract ,

```
p = re.findall(r'\b\d{6}\b',value)
```

and output is

```
[u'123456']
```

I have tried `int(p)` to get output as 123456 but its not working.

Comment: rather, `int(p[0])`

Comment: `p = [int(m) for m re.findall(r'\b\d{6}\b',value)]`

Comment: `re.findall()` is returning a list of strings.  You cannot cast an entire list to string.  You must first get the item out of the list and then pass it to `int()`.  Since your list has only one item doing `int(p[0])` would suffice.  But if you had more than one match you would probably want to convert each item in the returned list like so:  `[int(s) for s in p]`.  Then you would have a list of integers instead of a list of strings.

Comment: A general warning.  If this string of digits `'123456'` is part of an address element do not turn it into an integer.  When numbers are part of an address they are identifiers and pretty useless as numbers.  You don't do math on them.  The don't represent a quantity or magnitude of anything.  And by converting to a numeric representation you could end  up losing information.  What if you have a number where leading zeros are mean something?  They get lost in conversion.  What if `'12345XYZ'` becomes a valid address element?  Suddenly all your code is broken.  Just leave it a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ints = []
for s in p:
    ints.append(int(s))
```

Then use `ints` as you like.

**UPDATE**

If you are sure there will be one and only one integer, then do:

```
this_is_an_int = int(p[0])
```

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I gave it a countervailing upvote.  It does seem that the OP is expecting to match only one item.  So `int(p[0])` might be the best answer.  (Except then maybe the OP should be using `re.findall()`.)

Comment: Thanks @StevenRumbalski, I used a list because the OP didn't specify whether the string only contained one number or it could have contained more.

Comment: Hi ,The string will have only 1, 6 digit number

Comment: @jyotsna updated the answer

Comment: @andrea-f Thanks a lot ,My problem is solved